# How to reset xkb?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, xkb

I modified my /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc file. After doing so, my End and PgDn keys no longer work. I did not back up the file, but attempted to restore it manually with no results. Ctrl/Shift+End/PgDn still works, but End/PgDn doesn't register a key code in xkeybind or in my browser.

How do I reset xkb back to default?

I'm running Mint 18.

I've researched this extensively to no avail, and have found similar questions here, but no one with quite the same problem.

Answer (score 7):

#### Restoration of original file from Debian package after being modified or deleted

This is a generic answer that can work for any file that comes within a package (Not those generated later on runtime or after installation).

1. Check which package installs it

   ```
   dpkg -S /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc
   ```
2. Reinstall that package

   ```
   sudo apt reinstall <thatpackage>
   ```